# XSLT, facing issue in creating dynamic table

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to create a dynamic table for an xml file, but could get the data printed. Can you help in correcting it.

```
<xsl:template match="PageContents">



    <!-- Apply a template for each shape that isn't
         a Dynamic Connector. The shape's information
         will display as a row of the table. -->

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/PageContents/Shapes/Row[@N ='Dynamic connector']">


        <xsl:apply-templates select="/PageContents/Shapes"> 
                <xsl:sort select="not(Row[@N ='Environment']/Cell[@V ='QA'])"/>
                <xsl:sort select="not(Row[@N ='Environment']/Cell[@V ='Development'])"/>
                <xsl:sort select="not(Row[@N ='Environment']/Cell[@V ='Production'])"/>
                <xsl:sort select="Row[@N ='Environment']/Cell[@V]" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="Row[@N ='Topology_Reference_Number']/Cell[@V]" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="Row[@N ='Role']/Cell[@V]" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="Row[@N ='Location']/Cell[@V]" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="Row[@N ='SBB_Name']/Cell[@V]" order="ascending"/>

        </xsl:apply-templates>

        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>


            <!-- The Visio drawing does not have any 
                 Dynamic Connectors. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/PageContents/Shapes"> 


                <xsl:sort select="not(Row[@N ='Environment']/Cell[@V ='QA'])"/>
                <xsl:sort select="not(Row[@N ='Environment']/Cell[@V ='Development'])"/>
                <xsl:sort select="not(Row[@N ='Environment']/Cell[@V ='Production'])"/>
                <xsl:sort select="Row[@N ='Environment']/Cell[@V]" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="Row[@N ='Topology_Reference_Number']/Cell[@V]" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="Row[@N ='Role']/Cell[@V]" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="Row[@N ='Location']/Cell[@V]" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="Row[@N ='SBB_Name']/Cell[@V]" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

PFB sample XML data(Sorry couldn't attach complete table).

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
           - <PageContents xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/visio/2012/main"                  xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xml:space="preserve">
- <Shapes>
- <Shape ID="1" NameU="itsgShapeQA" IsCustomNameU="1" Name="itsgShapeQA" IsCustomName="1" Type="Shape" LineStyle="6" FillStyle="6" TextStyle="6">
  <Cell N="PinX" V="2.525" /> 
  <Cell N="PinY" V="11.155" /> 
  <Cell N="Width" V="1" U="IN" /> 
  <Cell N="Height" V="0.1" U="IN" /> 
  <Cell N="LocPinX" V="0.5" U="IN" F="Width*0.5" /> 
  <Cell N="LocPinY" V="0.05" U="IN" F="Height*0.5" /> 
  <Cell N="Angle" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="FlipX" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="FlipY" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="ResizeMode" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="EventDblClick" V="0" F="RUNMACRO("TAF___Visio_Template.ThisDocument.ITSGLabel_Click(QA)")" /> 
  <Cell N="LockWidth" V="1" /> 
  <Cell N="LockHeight" V="1" /> 
  <Cell N="LockMoveX" V="1" /> 
  <Cell N="LockMoveY" V="1" /> 
  <Cell N="LockDelete" V="1" /> 
  <Cell N="LockRotate" V="1" /> 
  <Cell N="LeftMargin" V="0.1111111111111111" U="PT" /> 
- <Section N="Character">
- <Row IX="0">
  <Cell N="Color" V="#0b0b0b" F="HSL(0,0,10)" /> 
  <Cell N="Size" V="0.1666666666666667" U="PT" /> 
  </Row>
  </Section>
<Section N="Geometry" IX="0">
  `enter code here`<Cell N="NoFill" V="1" /> 
  <Cell N="NoLine" V="1" /> 
  <Cell N="NoShow" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="NoSnap" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="NoQuickDrag" V="0" /> 
- <Row T="MoveTo" IX="1">
  <Cell N="X" V="0" U="IN" F="Width*0" /> 
  <Cell N="Y" V="0" U="IN" F="Height*0" /> 
  </Row>
- <Row T="LineTo" IX="2">
  <Cell N="X" V="1" U="IN" F="Width*1" /> 
  <Cell N="Y" V="0" U="IN" F="Height*0" /> 
  </Row>
- <Row T="LineTo" IX="3">
  <Cell N="X" V="1" U="IN" F="Width*1" /> 
  <Cell N="Y" V="0.1" U="IN" F="Height*1" /> 
  </Row>
- <Row T="LineTo" IX="4">
  <Cell N="X" V="0" U="IN" F="Width*0" /> 
  <Cell N="Y" V="0.1" U="IN" F="Height*1" /> 
  </Row>
- <Row T="LineTo" IX="5">
  <Cell N="X" V="0" U="IN" F="Geometry1.X1" /> 
  <Cell N="Y" V="0" U="IN" F="Geometry1.Y1" /> 
  </Row>
  </Section>
  <Text /> 
  </Shape>
<Shape ID="2" Type="Foreign" LineStyle="2" FillStyle="2" TextStyle="2" UniqueID="{DD01F26B-EABE-4B44-ABE4-1697851137B5}">
  <Cell N="PinX" V="4.251968503937007" /> 
  <Cell N="PinY" V="6.872303556765976" /> 
  <Cell N="Width" V="1.501223284589427" /> 
  <Cell N="Height" V="3.350906326130379" /> 
  <Cell N="LocPinX" V="0.7506116422947136" F="Width*0.5" /> 
  <Cell N="LocPinY" V="1.675453163065189" F="Height*0.5" /> 
  <Cell N="Angle" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="FlipX" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="FlipY" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="ResizeMode" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="ImgOffsetX" V="0" F="ImgWidth*0" /> 
  <Cell N="ImgOffsetY" V="0" F="ImgHeight*0" /> 
  <Cell N="ImgWidth" V="1.501223284589427" F="Width*1" /> 
  <Cell N="ImgHeight" V="3.350906326130379" F="Height*1" /> 
  <Cell N="ClippingPath" V="" F="No Formula" /> 
  <Cell N="TxtPinX" V="0.7506116422947136" F="Width*0.5" /> 
  <Cell N="TxtPinY" V="0" F="Height*0" /> 
  <Cell N="TxtWidth" V="1.501223284589427" F="Width*1" />   
  <Cell N="TxtHeight" V="0" F="Height*0" /> 
  <Cell N="TxtLocPinX" V="0.7506116422947136" F="TxtWidth*0.5" /> 
  <Cell N="TxtLocPinY" V="0" F="TxtHeight*0.5" /> 
  <Cell N="TxtAngle" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="VerticalAlign" V="0" /> 
- <Section N="Geometry" IX="0">
  <Cell N="NoFill" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="NoLine" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="NoShow" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="NoSnap" V="0" /> 
  <Cell N="NoQuickDrag" V="0" /> 
- <Row T="MoveTo" IX="1">
  <Cell N="X" V="0" F="Width*0" /> 
  <Cell N="Y" V="0" F="Height*0" /> 
  </Row>
- <Row T="LineTo" IX="2">
  <Cell N="X" V="1.501223284589427" F="Width*1" /> 
  <Cell N="Y" V="0" F="Height*0" /> 
  </Row>
- <Row T="LineTo" IX="3">
  <Cell N="X" V="1.501223284589427" F="Width*1" /> 
  <Cell N="Y" V="3.350906326130379" F="Height*1" /> 
  </Row>
- <Row T="LineTo" IX="4">
  <Cell N="X" V="0" F="Width*0" /> 
  <Cell N="Y" V="3.350906326130379" F="Height*1" /> 
  </Row>
- <Row T="LineTo" IX="5">
  <Cell N="X" V="0" F="Width*0" /> 
  <Cell N="Y" V="0" F="Height*0" /> 
  </Row>
  </Section>
```

XML has multiple rows and number of rows keep changing dynamically and i need to append all those data

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The PageContents element is in a namespace, but you are matching a PageContents element in no namespace.

Search for "XSLT default namespace" on this site or on google for many hundreds of posts that show you how to solve this.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your valuble suggestion. I was able to progress but facing problem in updating the table. Can you pls correct me in condition check.